# How to get the object who called DocumentFilter

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, documentfilter

Im making a sudoku game, I have 9x9 objects of type "cell" (class extends JTextField), i want to to prevent focusing on other JTextField objects if the user doesn't meet the game rules - his input(1-9) wont be at the same row or the same "block". To do this i need to know the specific object he is focused on.

One way i was thinking of doing that is by using DocumentFilter. I already filtered the input to digits and to 1 length, but i have no clue how to get that "cell" object he is focused on, Im pretty sure the DocumentFilter methods get that object somehow but i couldn't find how, any help?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`DocumentFilter` has reference to a `Document` but Documnets are just models. The same document instance can be set to more than one text component. Thus you won't be able to access `JTextField`.

You can extend the `DocumentFilter` and add a source `JTextField` directly. Just create as many as you need `DocumentFilter` for each your text field.